# how GEt image from database Django 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-3.0

I'm creating Blog on Django 3.0 Framework. so I crashed to a problem with Getting an image from Database. I can upload an image from admin and it's uploading in directory which I want to. When I'm entering image URL to Post I can see directory from Browser inspect. even the name of file but the image didn't show up.

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/uploadfiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/uploadfiles')
```

models.py

```
STATUS = (
(0,"Drafted"),
(1, "Published")

  )
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField('სიახლის სახელი', max_length=200)
    article_text = models.TextField('კონტენტი')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('თარიღი')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    imagecover = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploadfiles/postimages/', default='img-about1.jpg')


def __str__(self):
    return self.article_title

def Recently_published(self):
    return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(7))
```

Html File

```
 <div class="blog-post-image">
 <img src="{{a.imagecover.url}}" alt="image" class="img-responsive    center-block post_img" />
 </div>
```

Project Url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('article/', include('article.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
```

]

Comment: Can you share your project_url.py file settings

Comment: add this to your url 
urlpatterns = [
    path('article/', include('article.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this to your url file**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('article/', include('article.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Just copy the whole code above i have given and replace it with your existing url code

Comment: thank you very match <3 can you explain me what just we did and why we use in project url settings

Comment: It is to specify the path for the custom media path for our images and to let django know that from where it has to take up the media files .

And it is to be defined in the project url because it on project level and not on app level so it is to define one global path for all the media files of all apps.

For more you can refer to django documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('article/', include('article.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root = settings.STATIC_URL)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].